# NSFetchedResultsController Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSSortDescriptor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create a NSFetchedResultsController with a request to get photos from a specific region. I have two models Region and Photo in my core data. Below is my code of where I am getting the error:

```
- (void)setRegion:(Region *)region
{
    _region = region;

    // Making a request for the particular region
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromRegion = %@", region];
    NSLog(@"%@", region.name);

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:[region managedObjectContext]
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
}
```

I am receiving the following errors:

**-[NSSortDescriptor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d67850**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSSortDescriptor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d67850'**

I don't understand why I am receiving it. All I am doing is retrieving photos from the database that contains a specific region. However, I am receiving as error on the self.fetchedResultsController line. This core data tableview controller that contains this code is actually the designation view controller from another core data tableview controller.

I have looked around for other solutions but they only deal with problems related to looping through the self.fetchedResultsController which I am not doing. I am only displaying the photos in a tableview from the fetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Fetch requests use an array of sort descriptors, because you can provide more than one. That's why it's `sortDescriptors` instead of `sortDescriptor`. You need to provide an array. A simple fix is to change the line to create a one-element array containing your descriptor:

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

Additional evidence that this is the problem: `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` is a method that's defined by the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol. Since `NSArray` adopts that protocol, it would be expected to implement the method. But since `NSSortDescriptor` doesn't adopt that protocol, it would not have that method.

Comment: Man you saved the day. I can't believe I forgot to do something like this. Thanks so much.